# How to include Web Debug Toolbar in Symfony Response?

Tags: symfony

When I render a template and return a Response from a Controller, there is a nice Web Debug Toolbar on the bottom of the page.

Is it possible to make this bar appear when I don't use template and return a response by creating a Response object myself?

Answer (score 32):

It should be sufficient to make sure there is a valid `<body>...</body>`-block contained in the response-HTML-code. if the body-section is missing, then the debug toolbar won't appear.

Comment: sometimes when you do plain Responses without rendering a template, you don't send valid HTML.. So for me what fixed it was rendering a template

Comment: Amazing! They probably didn't want to break JSON/XML etc responses in dev environment by including toolbar into them! Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: This bugged me for over two years now. Nice to know, thank you!

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can also access the toolbar for JSON/XML (non-html) responses: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34810937/330267