# Always show toolbar in dev mode

Tags: php, symfony

I want to always display the toolbar in dev mode, not only on errors. I have the following method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) : JsonResponse
{
    return new JsonResponse($param);
}
```

that I run to test the toolbar. This generates an error of course because `$param` and the toolbar appears. But when I use `return new JsonResponse('aaa');` everything works and the toolbar does not appear.

How to make the toolbar appread even without errors?

config:

```
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/dev/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: true
```

AppKernel:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle();
}
```

Comment: By default it always on in dev, better ask: "what wrong I did that toolbar not showing".

Comment: You return a `JsonResponse` instance so there is no HTML Symfony could inject the toolbar markup into.

Comment: @SaschaM78 the answer you linked is not the right answer in this case.

Comment: @JakubZalas I already removed the misleading link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony injects the toolbar only in certain conditions, and only if the response is an html response. See the [WebDebugToolbarListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/b5f7196bf58094509b147aed883fe937639ca90d/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php#L99-L100) to learn how it's done. The listener [looks for the `</body>` tag](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/b5f7196bf58094509b147aed883fe937639ca90d/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/EventListener/WebDebugToolbarListener.php#L116) and injects the toolbar code before it.

If the listener injected the toolbar into a json response, it would make the response invalid.

You can still access the profile though, as the profiler link is included in the `X-Debug-Token-Link` header of the response. You can also find the profiler unique identifier in the `X-Debug-Token` header.

Note that the `X-Debug-Token-Link` header [was introduced in Symfony 2.4](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-quicker-access-to-the-profiler-when-working-on-an-api). Before you could only access the token.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed I can access it via X-Debug-Token.