# How can I include the Web Debug Toolbar in a symfony StreamedResponse?

Tags: php, symfony

When using a StreamedResponse in Symfony2/3, I cannot see the Web Debug Toolbar.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533658/how-to-include-web-debug-toolbar-in-symfony-response) indicates "there only needs to be valid HTML with a `<body>`", but even with this code

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $sr = new StreamedResponse();
    $sr->setCallback(function() {
        echo  "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Where is the bar?</title></head><body><p>Hi. Can I haz bar pleeze?</p></body></html>";
        flush();
    });
    $sr->send();
    return $sr;
    //return $this->render('index.html.twig');
}
```

I cannot make the bar appear.

Is this something related to the nature of the StreamedResponse?
Or is there someting I need to call on the response to let symfony know the bar should be added to this response as well?

Comment: Have you tried returning the response instead of calling send() yourself? I don't think you'll be able to see the toolbar as the response is not present at the time Symfony injects it. You should see the the token and link to the toolbar in the headers though.

Comment: Have you added "app_dev.php" to your URL? That should add the Web debug toolbar. You also need to edit the `@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` line in the `app_dev.php` file.